# Windows 7 - Create a VBS Script that will open a network location (the pause 10 seconds) and a folder on the desktop

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

Good day!

I'm trying to create a VBS script that will open up a location on a server share then pause 10 seconds, then open a folder on my desktop.

I can write a VBS in notepad that will open EXE's all day long but not locations like folders.  Here's just an example of where I'm going!

I'd like to double click a VBS and have the following happen (Examples)

Open  \Myshare\data\myfolder

pause 10 seconds

Open C:\Users\Mystuff\Desktop\Folder1

Exit

Any help would be great and thanks!  I'm a real novice...just for your FYI!!!

Comment: So please share the current state of your "trying".

Comment: Saying `VBS script` is like saying `TGIF Fridays`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're close then, you just need to remember that `explorer` is also an `EXE` file:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "Explorer " & "\\MachineName\Path\", 1, false
wscript.Sleep 10000
WshShell.Run "Explorer " & "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop", 1, false
```

should do similar to what you are after.

Comment: Jonno - I can't tell you how much you cleared this up simply saying "Explorer is an EXE".  I'm such a novice I just didn't even think about it!!!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @JDL2112 No problem ;) When you're confident your problem is solved, don't forget to click the 'Accept Answer' on an answer that helps you